# "Where In" with linq to sql

Tags: linq

I am trying to provide the user with a list of items in a database table upon entering keywords in a textbox. The problem i currently have is that the user can enter several keyword and i would like to be able to perform only one roundtrip to the database and get back results matchings several keywords (an OR operation). Is there a way to perform such a task without having to hit the database for every single keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [post](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) that offer a pretty good solution to what I was trying to achieve. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Contains() is your friend.

```
List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
keywords.Add("foo");
keywords.Add("bar");

var results = from item in db.Table
              where keywords.Contains(item.Description)
              select item;
```

...gives you

```
WHERE [t0].[Description] IN (@p0, @p1)
```

Comment: i would like to have something in the line of the google suggest box. the keyword does not have to be a perfect match

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) very useful when trying to figure out `LINQ` stuff in C#. It suggests [the following syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336760.aspx#WhereSimple1):

```
var results = from Item i in myCollectionOfItems
              where i.OneThing = aGoodThing || i.SomeStuff != theBadStuff
              select i;
```

EDIT: Sorry, misunderstood the question - I have updated to match the request for an `OR` operation. (I couldn't find the `||` syntax on the reference page, but I assume it will work. It [compiles on my machine](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000818.html)...

Answer (score 0):

tokenize your output for your keyword searches.

You can then just keep saying or in c# ( the || operator) in the where condition.

i.e

```
var query = from row in mytable
            where (row.column == a) || (row.column == b) || //.... etc
            select row
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try that :

```
List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
keywords.Add("foo");
keywords.Add("bar");

var results = from item in db.Table
              where keywords.Exists(k => item.Description.Contains(k))
              select item;
```

But I'm not sure it will convert to SQL...