# Linq IN Operator

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've tried searching for this but couldn't find examples that suited my situation.

I have this method for returning customers. How can I use the string array of codes to filter it? Contains doesn't work for me.

```
public static List<Customer> GetCustomers(string[] customerCodesArray)
{
    using (busDataContext g = new busDataContext())
    {
        return g.Customers.Where(
            x => x.customerCode.Contains(customerCodesArray)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify "what exactly" doesn't work...

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get a compile error? If so, what's the error? Or do you get a runtime error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Where In" with linq to sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960827/where-in-with-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
return g.Customers.Where(x => customerCodesArray.Contains(x.customerCode)).ToList();
```

Comment: Although technically correct, when using SQL this is not the best performing solution. It requires scanning the entire Customers table and most probably outer applying each record on the customer codes array. The complexity of this becomes O(N*M).

It would be more practical to use a Linq join statement, so the generated SQL query can use join too.

Comment: @TonniTielens That entirely depends on the indexes of the database. It will not necessarily generate a scan (and if it did, a join would fare no better, either). From my experience, inserting into a temp table and joining only provides performance benefits when `customerCodesArray` contains thousands of items.

Answer (score 21):

You are backwards:

```
return g.Customers.Where(x => customerCodesArray.Contains(x.customerCode)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 11):

I think you need to reverse the `Contains` expression because you want to see if the array contains the customer code, not the other way around.

Try this:

```
return g.Customers.Where(x => customerCodesArray.Contains(x.customerCode)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
return g.Customers.Where(x=>customerCodesArray.Contains(x.CustomerCode)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is what you want

```
    return g.Customers.Where(x => customerCodesArray.Contains(x.customerCode)).ToList();
```