# Linq where element.equals one array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i can simply get one item of an array by

```
   string myKeyword="test";
   GridView1.DataSource = from e in table where e.Keyword.Equals(myKeyword) select e;
```

how can i extend it to an array? I want something like:

```
   string[] myKeywords={"test1", "test"};
   GridView1.DataSource = from e in table where e.Keyword.Equals(myKeywords) select e; // something like this?
```

i want to get all elements where the Keyword is equal to one of the the Keywords in myKewords

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043151/linq-in-operator

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the [`Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) method:

```
var temp = (from e in table where myKeywords.Contains(e.Keyword)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] temp = (from e in table
                 join k in myKeywords on  e.Keyword equals k
                 select e.Keyword).ToArray();
```