# Use linq equivalent of sql IN operator

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have following linq statement in which I want to use linq equivalent of SQL IN operator. I have a string variable having values like  {1,2}.

```cs
    string items = "1,2";
    var objList = from p in db.firsttable 
                  join q in db.secondtable on q.id equals p.someid
                  where items.Contains(p.id)
                  select new 
                  {
                    p.id,
                    p.column1,
                    p.column2,
                    q.column3

                  }
```

But I am unable to get the output from the above linq statement. Please help me out.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043151/linq-in-operator)

Answer (score 3):

if `p.id` is string you should split the `items` values:

```
string[] items = "1,2".Split(',');
var objList = from p in db.firsttable 
          join q in db.secondtable on q.id equals p.someid
          where items.Contains(p.id)
          select new 
          {
            p.id,
            p.column1,
            p.column2,
            q.column3

          }
```

and if `p.id` is `int` you should split the `items` values and then parse them to `int`:

```
 int[] items = "1,2".Split(',').Select(x=> int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: And hoping that it isn't, I'd suggest using proper data types right away.

Comment: @vivek then add a `.ToString()` in the `Contains` method.

Comment: @vivek, I changed it for `int` types

Comment: @SteffenWinkler but it will again come to an error.Please edit your answer for objList linq statement, just in case if i am missing anythign

Comment: @TaherRahgooy Please edit your answer for objList linq statement, just in case if i am missing anythign

Comment: int[] array does not contains a definition for 'Contains'..  this is the error

Comment: @vivek Sorry, I used `.Split(",")` but the correct one is `.Split(',')`. Do you have `using System.Linq;` added?

Comment: @TaherRahgooy  its ok.. i have corrected it myself. yes i have already added the refrence.

Comment: @TaherRahgooy but it is not working in linq statement. I mean in objList statement.

Comment: @TaherRahgooy Error 8 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments ..... his is the full error message.

Comment: replace `items.Contains(p.id) ` with `items.Contains(1)` and see if works?

Comment: @TaherRahgooy but then with which attribue we are comparing "1" as we have to filter records having p.Id ==1 or 2 (in your case only 1)