# Translate query with operator 'IN' in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
select * 
from Enfants
where Enfants.id in 
(
   select EnfantParents.Enfant_Id 
   from EnfantParents 
   where EnfantParents.Parent_Id in 
   (
       select parents.Id 
       from Parents 
       where Parents.Id in 
       (
          select Reservations.ParentId 
          from Reservations 
          where Reservations.CrecheId = 1
       )
   )
 )
```

The EnfantParents is a hidden table.

I have Enfants `*-----*` Parents `1-----*` Reservations

Thank you .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq IN Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043151/linq-in-operator)

Comment: I don't think that you even need to use IN in this case. If you model your classes correctly, you can use navigational properties to create the query and such queries will be translated to SQL JOINs. Do you have navigational properties? Can you show your entity classes?

Comment: I think in SQL this query would have a better execution plan when using `EXISTS`, which would be the same as using `Any` in LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The EnfantParents is a hidden table

From the above I assume you are using EF with auto "link" table, your `Enfant` entity has `Parents` navigation property and your `Parent` entity has `Reservations` navigation property.

Then you can achieve the same result as the SQL query with a LINQ query like this:

```
var query = db.Enfants
    .Where(e => e.Parents.SelectMany(p => p.Reservations).Any(r => r.CrecheId == 1));
```