# How to run Linq on DataTable with SQL like 'IN' and return DataTable C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I'm trying to extract specific error lines from a DataTable:

In SQL this is my idea:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM [Main].[tableData] AS [D] 
WHERE [D].[Row Number] IN (
-- List<int> errorLineNumbers Here
)
```

Here is my C#:

```
DataTable mainDataTable = GetData();

List<int> errorLineNumbers errorLineNumbers = GerErrorLineNumbers(mainDataTable);

// This Crashes
DataTable errorDataTable = (from main in mainDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                            where main.Field<int>("Row Number").Equals(errorLineNumbers)
                            select main).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

This is the Exception: InvalidCastException

Specified cast is not valid.

I don't have a lot of experience with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In c# you'd be better off not dealing with `DataTable` directly. Represent your data a class and you can perform LINQ queries over a collection of that class. Using `DataTable` and `DataRow` involves a lot of tedious null checks and casts.

Comment: `where errorLineNumbers.Contains(main.Field<int>("Row Number"))`

Comment: I want to run this code on multiple different Data Tables. If I were to represent my data in a class. I'd have to create multiple different classes / models matching each table or resort to some dynamic class creation; which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: @mjwills Yes when I tried what you commented; I realized my "Row Number" column in my Data Table was a string type. When I changed that to int and tried your code. It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help. Post that as the answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq IN Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043151/linq-in-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *where* clause, you are trying to equal an `int` (the field value) to a `List<int>` object - naturally a cast will be attempted an then fail. Instead, try the following:

```
DataTable errorDataTable = (from main in mainDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                            where errorLineNumbers.Contains(main.Field<int>("Row Number"))
                            select main).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: :) Thanks for the help. @mjwills commented the same. Also: I realized my "Row Number" column in my Data Table was a string type. So I changed that to int and it worked perfectly.